# Chrome can't paste from desktop into CKEditor 4

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor

in Firefox it is possible to copy and paste an image into CKEditor from Word or even directly from the desktop itself. In any version of Chrome, however, it is not possible. I can't have Chrome users uploading images and then hotlinking to those images, so is there a workaround?

Chrome can easily go to any website, copy an image and paste into CKeditor. It just won't work from the user's machine, where most of these images are coming from.

Comment: In Firefox... How do the images appear? What is the HTML generated? Do you have something that uploads them or does CKE have this builtin? This sounds very very strange!

Comment: The images are converted to base64 by CKE, without any special plugin. There is nothing that uploads them.

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor using ImagePaste plugin it work only for Firefox.

You can try with doksoft_image_embed plugin. See demo here:

http://doksoft.com/soft/ckeditor-image-embed/demo.html

Unfortunately this plugin is Commercial License.

Or you can try with Base64 Image:

Base64 Image will replace ImagePaste, Button Upload image as base64 into CKEditor:

[image]

http://ckeditor.com/addon/base64image